# Function Trace and memory profiling Python for large projects

Tags: python, out-of-memory, trace, memory-profiling

I have a Python large project (in Linux) which will eat an insane amount of memory easily (30G+). The program will run all the system memory and then get killed. This as you can imagine, is difficult to debug or diagnosis the location of the problem.

I have tried to perform a memory profile on this, but a [memory profile](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) However, the problem is that this gives results as soon as the program ends, and the project is large, and I cannot place a @profile decorator on every function.

I have also tried a trace using pdb and was hoping for a better stack info for when the program dies, but this didn't give adequate results.

Is there something like Valgrind for python ? Or some way to get what functions are using up this memory before the program runs out of memory?

Forgive my English )